# Colliding with objects(walls)

Tags: javascript, canvas

What a good practice to detect collision of 2 objects(walls). Yes, not just detection, but further displacement so that objects do not enter each other. That is, so that when they collide, they rest against each other, but do not enter.

[CODE](https://codepen.io/Mbreti/pen/YzqMoEP?editors=1010)

```
class WallObj {
    constructor(obj) {//x, y, w, h, bern ,thru) {
        this.x = obj.x
        this.y = obj.y
        this.w = obj.w
        this.h = obj.h
        this.bern = obj.bern
        this.thru = obj.thru
        this.hide = obj.hide
        this.id = obj.id
    }

    collusionWall(startPosition, endPosition) {
        var xS = startPosition[0]
        var x = endPosition[0]

        if (xS - x > 0)
            if (x)
                // if wall behind point
                if (this.x < startPosition[0])
                    return endPosition
                else if (this.x + this.w < x)
                    return endPosition

        return endPosition

        // return [this.x, endPosition[1]]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a naive approach would be to check x and y :

```js
let ctx = mycan.getContext("2d");
let objects = [];

class player 
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.position = {x:50,y:50};
   this.color = "blue";
    this.size = 32;
    this.stop= false;
    this.prevpos=this.position;
    window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
      if(this.stop) this.position=this.prevpos;
      else this.displacement(e);
    });
  }
  
   displacement(e)
   {
      this.prevpos = this.position;
      this.position.x+=(e.key=="ArrowRight");
      this.position.x-=(e.key=="ArrowLeft");
      this.position.y+=(e.key=="ArrowDown");
      this.position.y-=(e.key=="ArrowUp");
   }
  
  draw()
  {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;  ctx.fillRect(this.position.x,this.position.y,this.size,this.size);
  }
};

class wall
{
  constructor(posx,posy)
  {
   this.position = {x:posx,y:posy};
   this.color = "red";
   this.size = 32;
   }
   
   draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.position.x,this.position.y,this.size,this.size);
   }
};

for(let i = 0; i<mycan.width;i+=32)
{
  objects.push(new wall(i,0));
  objects.push(new wall(i,mycan.height-32));
}

for(let j = 0; j<mycan.height;j+=32)
{
  objects.push(new wall(0,j));
  objects.push(new wall(mycan.width-32,j));
}

let playr=new player;


let collision = (colider)=>{
let colx = false;
let coly = false;
/*******************************************************
here we check if the top left point from our current
wall object is inferior to the top left point of our
player and if the top rignt point of the wall object is
superior to the player top left point.
we need to repeat this for the player top right point 
(so we compare the player top right point is superior
to the wall top left point and inferior to the wall 
top right point)
then we repeat this for y
*******************************************************/
  for(let object of objects)
  {
    colx = (
    (
    (object.position.x<=colider.position.x) && 
    (
    (object.position.x+object.size)>=
    (colider.position.x)
    )
    )||(
 (
 (colider.position.x+colider.size)>=object.position.x) && 
 (
 (colider.position.x+object.size)<=(object.position.x+object.size)
 )
 )
 )
    coly = (
    (
    (object.position.y<=colider.position.y) && 
    (
    (object.position.y+object.size)>=
    (colider.position.y)
    )
    )||(
 (
 (colider.position.y+colider.size)>=object.position.y) && 
 (
 (colider.position.y+object.size)<=(object.position.y+object.size)
 )
 )
 )
 if(colx&&coly) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

setInterval(()=>{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,mycan.width,mycan.height);
  playr.stop = collision(playr);
  playr.draw();
  for(let obj of objects)
    obj.draw();
},1000/30);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycan" width=400 height=250></canvas>
```

à better approach would be to cut your 2d world into zones where the density of objects that can collide is more or less important (a quadtree).

like so :

[image]

and an easier way would be to look if the colided object is in a sphere (this would mean that walls have a spheric collision and could hardly be represented as a square) but we could just say that the player is a sphere and check if something has entered his radius.

https://studiofreya.com/3d-math-and-physics/sphere-vs-aabb-collision-detection-test/